# SSRS result different from SSMS result with the same query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am comparing the result of my SQL query to my SSRS report with the same query on it's dataset but I noticed that the result is lesser in SSRS compare to SQL.

I tested it a lot of times and make sure I had the same parameter selected in my report and the same value entered in my SQL query but I still not had the same result. Can anyone help me with this? I really can't see the problem. I also did checked all the filters in my SSRS report but I had no filter on any objects there.

```
SELECT ZR.CURRENT_PROD_SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU
  ,LGEO.LEVEL6 AS CUSTOMER_COUNTRY
  ,LGEO.LEVEL1 AS CUSTOMER_REGION
  ,ZR.BILLTO_IBR_CSR_ENTITY_NAME AS CUSTOMER_NAME
  ,ZR.CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME AS PROD_DIV
  ,LDATE.PER_NAME_MONTH
  ,SUM(ZR.RPTDPOSRECORDUNITSSOLD) AS QUANTITY
  ,SUM(ZR.PRICEC_EUR) AS PRICEC_EUR
    FROM View_ZR_Birst_Raw ZR
    LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_DATE LDATE ON ZR.POS_INVOICE_DATE = LDATE.DAY_DT
    LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_GEO_MASTER LGEO ON LGEO.COUNTRY = ZR.BILLTO_IBR_CSR_COUNTRY
    WHERE ZR.POS_INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND LGEO.LEVEL6 IN (SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.[FnSplit](@Country,','))
    AND ZR.CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME IN (SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.[FnSplit](@ProductDivision,','))
    AND ZR.CURRENT_PROD_SKU IN (SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.[FnSplit](@SKU,','))
    GROUP BY ZR.CURRENT_PROD_SKU 
  ,LDATE.PER_NAME_MONTH
  ,LGEO.LEVEL6 
  ,LGEO.LEVEL1
  ,ZR.BILLTO_IBR_CSR_ENTITY_NAME
  ,ZR.CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER_REGION,CUSTOMER_COUNTRY,BILLTO_IBR_CSR_ENTITY_NAME,PROD_DIV,PRODUCT_SKU
    OPTION (MAXDOP 4)
```

I used [FnSplit] function in my WHERE Clauses. This function is just basically for splitting comma-separated value from multiselect parameter because my script was originally in SP so that's why I used it.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can use cached datasets - switch this off.

Also - if using it within the designer you delete the *reportname.data* to remove the local chached version.